# Rails radio button nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, nested-forms

I wan to make primary phone number from rails nested form. My model associations:

```
# customer.rb

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :telephones, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :telephones, allow_destroy: true
end

# telephone.rb

class Telephone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  enum status: {primary: 1, secondary: 0}
end
```

my form :

```
# _form.html.haml

= form_with(model: customer, local: true) do |form|
 ....
 .....
 = form.fields_for :telephones do |builder|                                                          
   = render 'telephone_fields', form: builder                                                        
 = link_to_add_fields "Add Telephone", form, :telephone
```

in my partial views telephone_fields, like this:

```
# _telephone_fields

%fieldset
  .form-group
    = form.label :content, 'Telephone'

    = form.label :status
    = form.radio_button :status, "primary"
```

but, it's not correct, because all radio button can be selected.

Maybe someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to allow only `primary` phones in the form?

Comment: Yes, when I click one of them, another radio should be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write JS code. Basically, give some class to radio buttons. Add listener, check value and if it's selected (primary) for some item - hide for others.

Comment: Can you give me the example?